# upload list of lists to firebase realtime database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to upload some files and pics to firebase store and realtime database but data will be categorized
[in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNIfF.png)
in realtime and storage.

I can successfully achieve that in storage, but I can't do it in realtime.

This is my code to upload data to firebase storage and realtime database

```
private void uploadFilesToStorage(String userKey, List<Uri> list, String listName) {
    StorageReference mReference = sReference.child(mycertificate.getCert_num()
            + "/");
    urls = new ArrayList<>();
    wholeList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Uri uri : list) {
        StorageReference sr = mReference.child(listName + "/"
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + "."
                + Tools.getFileExtn(BrowseFiles.this,
                uri));
        sr.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                sr.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        urls.add(uri.toString());
                        wholeList.put(listName,urls);
                        Model model = new Model(userKey, mycertificate.getCert_num(),
                                mycertificate.getCert_date(), mycertificate.getComp_name(),
                                mycertificate.getComp_num(), mycertificate.getCountry(),
                                mycertificate.getTrans(), mycertificate.isModel_13(),
                                mycertificate.isChk_fact(), mycertificate.getOffers()
                                , wholeList);

                        uploadDataToRTDB(model);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

private void uploadDataToRTDB(Model model) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Database");
    reference.child("myfiles")
            .child(modal.getCert_num).setValue(model);
}
```

and I call it in main activity like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylists.size(); i++) {
    uploadFilesToStorage(UUID, mylists.get(i),
         fragmentsIndx.get((i + 1)));
}
```

**mylists** is a List<List < Uri>> and filled with all lists I want to upload.

when I run my app I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtgNx.jpg) in realtime database:

[image]

***all urls added to all categories.***

So how can I solve this?

***Edit***
this is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mkandeel.kodsadmin"
    compileSdk = 33

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mkandeel.kodsadmin"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.2.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.2.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.1")
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1")
    // retrofit
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
// GSON
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")
    // okhttp3
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.3")
}
```

this is my model class

```
package com.mkandeel.kodsadmin.models;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Model {
    private String cert_num;
    private String cert_date;
    private String comp_name;
    private String comp_num;
    private String country;
    private String trans;
    private boolean model_13;
    private boolean isFact;
    private String offers;
    private List<List<String>> lists;
    private String userKey;


    public Model(){}

    public Model(String userKey,String cert_num, String cert_date, String comp_name, String comp_num, String country, String trans, boolean model_13, boolean isFact, String offers, List<List<String>> lists) {
        this.cert_num = cert_num;
        this.cert_date = cert_date;
        this.comp_name = comp_name;
        this.comp_num = comp_num;
        this.country = country;
        this.trans = trans;
        this.model_13 = model_13;
        this.isFact = isFact;
        this.offers = offers;
        this.lists = lists;
        this.userKey = userKey;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getLists() {
        return lists;
    }

    public void setLists(List<List<String>> lists) {
        this.lists = lists;
    }

    public String getUserKey() {
        return userKey;
    }

    public void setUserKey(String userKey) {
        this.userKey = userKey;
    }


    public String getCert_num() {
        return cert_num;
    }

    public void setCert_num(String cert_num) {
        this.cert_num = cert_num;
    }

    public String getCert_date() {
        return cert_date;
    }

    public void setCert_date(String cert_date) {
        this.cert_date = cert_date;
    }

    public String getComp_name() {
        return comp_name;
    }

    public void setComp_name(String comp_name) {
        this.comp_name = comp_name;
    }

    public String getComp_num() {
        return comp_num;
    }

    public void setComp_num(String comp_num) {
        this.comp_num = comp_num;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getTrans() {
        return trans;
    }

    public void setTrans(String trans) {
        this.trans = trans;
    }

    public boolean isModel_13() {
        return model_13;
    }

    public void setModel_13(boolean model_13) {
        this.model_13 = model_13;
    }

    public boolean isFact() {
        return isFact;
    }

    public void setFact(boolean fact) {
        isFact = fact;
    }

    public String getOffers() {
        return offers;
    }

    public void setOffers(String offers) {
        this.offers = offers;
    }


}
```

Comment: You're calling `.setValue(modal)`. That should probably be `.setValue(model)`.

Comment: I am sorry that was copying mistake but this is not error I edited it here, thank you

Comment: incliude the code of app level build.gradle. I will tell you, where you are doing mistake.

Comment: Your code is fine. I think you are doing mistake in Model class. Share your Model.java file also.

Comment: I edited question to add my model class

Comment: Check answer what I posted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to make a list of lists in realtime database each sub list has its own size and data
but what I got all lists have the same data and same size however it's categories well in firebase storage

Comment: Can you please show us what is your desired result?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added it already in the question I added a picture for desired result and actual result